statically indeterminate problem with two unknown reaction moments
I have the following statically indeterminate problem: two journal bearings (A and B) supporting a rod with W as its uniformly distributed weight (known). It might be relatively safe to assume that the reaction moment at A and B is negligible, but I would still like to know what method can be used to solve the problem.



I have written a short ap with arbitrary numbers assigned to your original sketch, written in Basic for clarity, to show some relative results. Hopefully you can relate my nomenclature to your sketch where the rod extends from left (zero) to right (C=12). The ap is located at: https://www.keepandshare.com/doc18/31420/rodmoment-pdf-43k?da=y .
Regards, DaveM2 12-04-2024

The problem can be solved using singularity functions.
Bending Moment M(x) taken from C with  x +ve towards A yields.
$M(x) = \frac{-W}{2}\langle x-0\rangle^2 - M_b\langle x-L_{bc}\rangle^0 -M_a\langle x-(L_{bc}+L_{ab})\rangle^0 + B_y\langle x-L_{bc}\rangle^1 + A_y\langle x-(L_{bc}+L_{ab})\rangle^1$
The $M_a\langle x-(L_{bc}+L_{ab})\rangle^0$ and $A_y\langle x-(L_{bc}+L_{ab})\rangle^1$ terms are zero as x at point A is equal to $L_{ab}+L{_bc}$.
You then can, as $EI\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =-M(x) $, integrate twice to obtain Slope after the first integration : $(EI\frac{dy}{dx})$ and Deflection : $(EIy)$ after the second.
If A and B are journal bearings there is no reaction moment as they do not resist moments.
As such the problem is statically determinate (I didn't realise this at first), it does mean that the above method is overcomplicating things as it can be resolved using equilibrium equations.

Why would you be so certain there isn't a reaction moment in the z-direction? The journal bearing does resist rotation around the z-axis (perpendicular to the xy plane).

A journal bearing is used to allow a shaft to rotate freely. So the structure is determinate and the supports are unable to carry a moment.

@CapBul From the diagram provided in the question there isn't anything that suggests any forces/moments acting in the z-direction. If there are they aren't shown on the diagram. What is the problem you initially asked ? Are you tasked with finding the forces/moments or something else?

I refer to the moments on the diagram as acting in the z direction due to convention. I haven't studied yet how to deal with statically indeterminate problems so I'm asking for advice about which method to use to solve it. Yes, the end goal is to solve for all reaction forces and moments.

@kamran I feel like there is a misunderstanding. I've added an image of the exact bearing I refer to with all reaction forces.

So the y axis in the drawing of the bearing is the line joining A to C in the first diagram? That is you have a shaft in bending. If so, you need to know the structural properties of the shaft and the rotational stiffness about the out of screen axis of the bearings.
